# Появляющаяся форма для ввода текста

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, php, javascript

К примеру, у меня имеется одна форма для ввода ника:

```
<input type='text' name='nick'>
```

И поле для другого текста:

```
<input type='text' name='text'>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы когда я переключился с поля nick на другое, то выполнился php скрипт и при надобности вывел поле password? Без перезагрузки страницы естественно.

Требуется для того, чтобы проверить, если такой ник зарегистрирован в системе, то при добавлении текста, человек должен ввести свой пароль.

Comment: [ AJAX](http://www.google.com/m?q=Ajax&client=ms-opera-mobile&channel=new)  
[DOM]( http://www.google.com/search?client=ms-opera-mobile&channel=new&sky=ee&hl=ru&ie=UTF-8&q=dom)
1. Асинхронно спрашиваете у сервера, есть ли такой ник в системе.  
2. Сервер должен ответить да или нет.  
3. Смотрите ответ сервера.  
4. Уведомляете пользователя в соответствии с результатом ответа

Comment: по сути отправить запрос могу, а как вот узнать, что юзер перешел к другому полю?

Comment: выполняйте аякс запрос по событию фокус поля "текст", или при потере фокуса поля "ник". В зависимости от логики страницы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример js обработчика:

```
//событие сработает при потере фокуса поля nick
$('#nick').blur(function() {
  //посылаем запрос на некую страницу test.php
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ajax/test.php',
    data: { nick: $('#nick').val() },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
    //при успешном исходе получаем данные в перменную data и обрабатываем их
      if (data=='show_pass_input') {
        $('#pass').show();
      } else {
        $('#pass').hide();
      }
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      //если ошибка аякса, то выведем ее
      alert(xhr.status);
      alert(thrownError);
    } 
  });
});
```

Далее создаем страницу PHP, где забираем переменную nick  `$_POST['nick']`, обрабатываем ее и, скажем, если нужно показать поле пароль, то выводим: `echo("show_pass_input");` (как пример)

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Как раз то что нужно. 
Сейчас уже нашел свою старую книжку, там искал способы. Но не нашел)